# Connecting a VB.NET application with a Google Docs Spreadsheet

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a small application that can order stuff. The way a user can order something is to input the correct information through a google form, which then would be automatically converted to a Google Spreadsheet.

Now, I want to connect it to my VB application. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: You have to tell what you tried before asking help to the community. `"Provide details. Share your research."`

Answer (score 1):

You should install sheetsapi v4 to your app.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form3
    Shared Scopes As String() = {SheetsService.Scope.SpreadsheetsReadonly}
    Shared ApplicationName As String = "Google Sheets API .NET Quickstart"


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim credential As UserCredential
        Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim credPath As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json")

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString("Credential file saved to: ") & credPath)
        End Using

        Dim service = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
    .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
    .ApplicationName = ApplicationName })
      Dim spreadsheetId As [String] = "your sheet id"

        Dim range As [String] = "A2:F"

        Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.[Get](spreadsheetId, range)
        Dim response As ValueRange = request.Execute()
        Dim values As IList(Of IList(Of [Object])) = response.Values
        Dim son As String

        If values IsNot Nothing AndAlso values.Count > 0 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Name, Major")

            For Each rol In values
                son = rol(0) + "  " + rol(1) + "  " + rol(2) + "  " + rol(4)

                ' Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                ListBox1.Items.Add(son)

            Next
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```